# Finding Combat Records of Ancestor's Unit from World War 2

Tags: united-states, military-records, world-war-2

I started doing research on the service history for my grandmother's brother who died in Europe during the second World War. I have his serial number and his unit (K Company, 110th Infantry Regiment, 28th Infantry Division), and I also know that he sustained serious wounds in France on October 1st, 1944, then later died of his wounds in a hospital in Belgium on October 5th, 1944. We have this pieced together from local newspaper reports when his body was repatriated and other easily accessible online sources.

Where I'm running into issues is trying to find out the events leading to my great-uncle's death. I found this PDF titled [US Army Units, Book 4 Boxes 748-902](https://www.eisenhowerlibrary.gov/sites/default/files/finding-aids/pdf/us-army-unit-records-4.pdf) on the Eisenhower Library website (p. 86 in the document), which seems to suggest that after-action reports and other information may exist for his unit, but I cannot determine if they exist online or where I would start searching for them if they do.

It seems as if I have a decent amount of information but I'm not sure where to start getting more detailed battle history.

Do you have any suggestions or advice on how to work through these documents?